# how to simulate bluetooth on android emulator

Tags: android, bluetooth

I used this [project](https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator) to simulate the bluetooth on android emulator.
I have 2 classes one enabling the bluetooth

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    BluetoothAdapter.SetContext(this);

    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(adapter==null) { 
        System.out.println("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
      return;
    }

    if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
        adapter.enable();
    }
    }
```

another scan for devices and list them

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        BluetoothAdapter.SetContext(this);

        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        System.out.println("\nAdapter: " + adapter);

        if(adapter==null) { 
            System.out.println("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
          return;
        }

        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            adapter.enable();
        }

        if (adapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            adapter.startDiscovery();
        }


        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            System.out.println("Found device: " + device);
        }
    }
```

the second device doesn't detect any devices, so what's wrong with my code?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to put some log out in your code to see whats going on, what methods are being ran etc

Comment: i did that and realized that the "devices" set it's length is zero!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() returns the default local adapter.
It returns null if the device doesn't have Bluetooth capability and since you are using the emulator which doesn't support Bluetooth it will return null.